# Dask some tasks not scheduled to worker with resources constraints

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I need to submit some tasks of my pipeline to a specific Dask's worker. I have used [worker resources](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/resources.html#worker-resources) on worker initialization:

```
dask worker dask-scheduler:8786 --no-dashboard --nthreads 1 --nworkers 2 --memory-limit 6GB --resources "process=1"
```

In my pipeline code, I have defined a `delayed` function with `annotate` resources:

```py
from dask import delayed, annotate

with annotate(resources={'process': 1}):
     process_delayed_func = delayed(delayed_func, pure=pure)
```

then I use `process_delayed_func` in my pipeline with other delayed functions.
Then I `compute` my pipeline with `optimize_graph=False`.

I could `compute` my pipeline multiple times, with different parameters` so multiple instances of the same pipeline are running at the same time.

Sometimes my `process_delayed_func` function runs on the correct worker sometimes ( in another pipeline) the function runs in a worker not annotated with `process` resources.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Why sometimes resources are not respected by Dask?

Comment: To clarify: you have two workers here with process=1, and you also have some other workers elsewhere?

Comment: @mdurant I have a cluster with some workers annotated with `process` and other workers not annotated.

Comment: I found the problem I guess. My `delayed_func` is a partial function so when I add it to my pipeline with parameters `process_delayed_func(parameters)` it lost the resource annotation.

Comment: If you can describe this as an answer to your own question, you will help out other users.